# In-exact line search

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

In my class notes, the author says:

"If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded below and $p_k$ is a descent direction and the $\alpha-\beta$ also known as Armijo-Goldstein condition is met then either $\nabla f(x_k) \to 0$ or the angle between $\nabla f(x_k)$ and $p_k$ approaches 90 degrees."

I think the author meant $\| \nabla f(x_k) \| \to 0$ as this would imply that we are approaching the stationary point of $f$??

or in the worst case scenario $\nabla f(x_k)$ and $p_k$ becomes orthogonal.
It means that $p_k$ still decreases the $f$ but the rate of decrease decreases?

Comment: $\nabla f(x_k) \to 0$ is  is equivalent to $\|\nabla f(x_k) \|\to0$

Comment: Ah yes from the properties of the norm